# Why is a conditional distribution harder to evaluate than a joint distribution in variational Bayes?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, information-theory, bayesian

I'm hoping that someone can supply me with some intuition that seems to be escaping me. I'm trying to get a handle on the mathematics of the free energy principle (FEP), which is a variational Bayesian model applied to how an organism models its environment. My main guide is to be found in [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022249617300962), which walks through the mathematics. Where my problem lies is in a distinction made between conditional and joint probability distributions.

The FEP claims that it's usually intractable for an organism to calculate the divergence between a 'true' probability distribution, *P*, across states of the environment given sensory data, *s*, and its model distribution, *Q*:

$$D_{KL}(Q||P) = \sum_{v_i\in V} \log q(v_i)\frac{q(v_i)}{p(v_i|s)}$$

I understand this well enough and it needs no explaining. Where I get puzzled is when this expression is re-arranged to generate the equivalent expressions below:

$$D_{KL}(Q||P) = \sum_{v_i\in V} \log q(v_i)\frac{q(v_i)}{p(v_i,s)} + \log p(s)$$

It's claimed that the joint distribution $p(v_i,s)$ is easier to evaluate than the conditional distribution $p(v_1|s)$. However, I don't understand why this should be any easier. After all, the organism still needs access to a distribution that covers all possible states of the environment in the joint distribution. So, either I'm not getting some mathematical fact here, or there are non-mathematical reasons why the jpint distribution is easier to estimate.

If the reason is mathematical, can anyone give me some guidance on what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\log$ using `\log`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: That's a very long paper, and it has numbered equations; where in the paper are you referring to?

Comment: The specific equations that interest me are the equations from (2) to (7). Thanks!